# Is it possible to track gps location in the background in phonegap application on IPhone?

Tags: iphone, android, geolocation, cordova

Phonegap can watch location (W3C watchLocation) in the background on Android devices. I've tested it on my Samsung Galaxy Ace. Have anybody tested this on IPhone. Can it watch location when user switch to another app or perhaps received a call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not.
When Safari in background, is no geolocation icon on toolbar and no tracking with watchPosition.

If Safari in foreground and phone display turned off watchPosition is working.
And when phone is recieves a call is working too.